# Unity engine vs JS engine for browser game

Tags: game-design

I'm trying to do a browser based game and I don't want to create my own game engine, no sense in recreating the wheel.  Should I use Unity as my game engine?  Or should I focus on a more Javascript based engine like Impact since it will be a browser game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity3D is a good candidate with WebGL support coming soon in version 5. S,o no plugin in the browser is required. You also can program it in JavaScript.

[Info about it here](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/04/29/on-the-future-of-web-publishing-in-unity/)

Comment: So, if I understand the article correctly.  WebGL will allow Unity rendered 3D animations and images to 'natively' run in the browser?

Comment: @Robert Yes. The [performance](http://beta.unity3d.com/jonas/WebGLBenchmark/) is already great.